# Including header from the same file on every platform

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation, cross-platform, header-files

I have a file `cpp-options.txt` in which I have written every compiler option I use to compile my C++ programs.

I have [made an alias](https://superuser.com/a/115259) `g+` as `g++ @/path/to/cpp-options.txt $*` , so that whenever I invoked `g+ prog.cpp`, from anywhere on my computer, the program is compiled with all the compiler options from that file.

Now I want to add another option which includes a header file `header.h` in the options file. This file is always kept on the same directory as the `cpp-options.txt` file.
So, now the `cpp-options.txt` file looks like this -:

`-Wall -Wextra.....`
**`-include /path/to/header.h`**

Now, this setup works on Windows perfectly, but wont work on Linux, as the absolute path to the options file on Linux would be something like this -:

`/mnt/media......../absolute/path/to/header.h`

So, the compiler would complain about the absence of any such file on Linux.
Now I am aware of one solution of this problem, that is to include the folder in which these two files are kept in the `PATH` environment variable on both the Operating Systems and then simply writing -:

`-Wall -Wextra.....`
**`-include header.h`**

However, I dont want to *pollute* the PATH variables.
Is there any other way of accomplishing this ?

Comment: Make symbolic links (or forks on Windows) so the path is the same on both systems?

Comment: I dont get it. How did it solve the problem ?

Comment: If the path is equal on all systems, then you can use that path in the parameter file. It doesn't really matter if the path is the actual hard path to the file or one or more symbolic links to the file.

Comment: But that's the problem ! No file on Windows can have the same path on Linux. It is always appended with `/mnt/media...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best I could do was to create another common file `cpp-options-common.txt` which contained only the the compiler options (-Wall, -Wextra, -std=c++14 etc), and shift the `-include /path/to/header.h` statement to the `cpp-options.txt` file.
Also, I imported the `cpp-options-common.txt` file into the `cpp-options.txt` file by using the `@` GCC compiler directive.

My final configuration -:

*cpp-options-common.txt* -: ( located in the Windows partition )

```
-Wall -Wextra -Wfatal-errors ...
```

**On Windows -:**

*cpp-options.txt -:*

```
@path/to/cpp-options-common.txt
-include path/to/header.h
```

**Linux -:**

*cpp-options.txt -:*

```
@/media/Data/path/to/cpp-options-common.txt
-include /media/Data/path/to/header.h
```